# Swift Iterate through array of date intervals

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dateinterval

In my iOS app i have a list of events that each have a start and end date. My goal is to figure out which events overlap each other - meaning, if event1 starts Mon, oct 6 @ 2:30 pm and ends at 5:30 pm and event4 starts Mon, oct 6 @ 3:30 pm. I need to know that those two events overlap.

So When downloading the data from the web, i create an array of `[DateInterval]`with each `EventObjects` start date and end date respectively.

My question is, what's the best way to iterate though the eventObjects array and then check if the start dates intersect with the `[DateInterval]` dates?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

here is an example code..

```
func sortArray (){

  for object in sortedEventObjectArray {


        let hasConflics = zip(datesReversed, datesReversed.dropFirst()).contains(where: { $0.end > $1.start })

        if hasConflics == true {
            print("conflict")
        } else {
            print("none")
        }

    }
}

[sortedEventObjectArray] is an event object which contains details like the start date and end date of event - this is what i used to populate the datesReserved array of Date Intervals

[datesReversed] is an array of DateIntervals - it looks like this

[2018-11-01 06:00:00 +0000 to 2018-11-01 09:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-01 18:00:00 +0000 to 2018-11-01 19:33:00 +0000, 2018-11-01 19:33:00 +0000 to 2018-11-01 23:00:00 +0000, 2018-11-03 18:14:00 +0000 to 2018-11-03 21:44:00 +0000, 2018-11-03 18:14:00 +0000 to 2018-11-03 21:44:00 +0000, 2018-11-06 12:00:00 +0000 to 2018-11-06 13:26:00 +0000, 2018-11-06 13:27:00 +0000 to 2018-11-06 14:00:00 +0000, 2018-11-06 17:00:00 +0000 to 2018-11-06 22:00:00 +0000, 2018-11-06 18:00:00 +0000 to 2018-11-06 21:00:00 +0000, 2018-11-07 12:00:00 +0000 to 2018-11-07 14:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-07 18:30:00 +0000 to 2018-11-07 23:00:00 +0000, 2018-11-08 11:30:00 +0000 to 2018-11-08 12:59:00 +0000, 2018-11-08 12:56:00 +0000 to 2018-11-08 13:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-08 19:30:00 +0000 to 2018-11-08 22:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-09 12:30:00 +0000 to 2018-11-09 14:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-09 15:00:00 +0000 to 2018-11-09 16:00:00 +0000, 2018-11-09 16:30:00 +0000 to 2018-11-09 21:00:00 +0000, 2018-11-09 20:00:00 +0000 to 2018-11-09 21:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-10 12:30:00 +0000 to 2018-11-10 20:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-10 13:45:00 +0000 to 2018-11-10 14:30:00 +0000, 2018-11-10 18:00:00 +0000 to 2018-11-10 19:00:00 +0000]
```

The output i get is - (Which is wrong because its clear that some of those dates do not have scheduling conflicts )

```
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
conflict
```

Comment: @MartinR can you please try the pseudo code on this post from our earlier conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An efficient solution is to *sort* the events by increasing start date first. Then you only have to compare each event with those that start later.

If the model object is

```
struct Event {
    let title: String
    let duration: DateInterval
}
```

then it could look like this (untested):

```
var events: [Event] = ...
events.sort(by: { $0.duration.start < $1.duration.start })
for i in events.indices.dropLast() {
    for j in (i + 1)..<events.endIndex {
        if events[i].duration.end > events[j].duration.start {
            print(events[i].title, "overlaps with", events[j].title)
        } else {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Note hat the inner loop can terminate if a non-overlapping event is found, because the events are sorted by increasing start date.

If you only need to know if *any* events overlap then it suffices to compare each event duration with the duration of the following event:

```
var events: [Event] = ...
events.sort(by: { $0.duration.start < $1.duration.start })
var hasConflicts = false
for i in events.indices.dropLast() {
    if events[i].duration.end > events[i+1].duration.start {
        hasConflics = true
        break
    }
}
```

Using `zip` this code can be shorted to

```
var events: [Event] = ...
events.sort(by: { $0.duration.start < $1.duration.start })
let hasConflics = zip(events, events.dropFirst())
    .contains(where: { $0.duration.end > $1.duration.start })
```

Comment: thanks for the response! I am believing that the second one is going to be the best option. Im trying to implement that function now. I believe it has to be inside of some type of loop though for it to iterate through the entire array, correct ?

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading: `zip(events, events.dropFirst())` “magically” iterates over all pairs of adjacent array elements.

Comment: Hey @MartinR i added some example code to my post. Hopefully this may be something you can point my mistake out in.. thanks

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading: The second (zip) solution was meant only for determining if there is *any* conflict, it makes not sense to do that in a loop. – I suggest to try my first solution.

Comment: Oh i understand what you mean! I would try the nested loop but i am trying to get better performance On2

Comment: the main thing is i need to be able to perform this algorithm within a nested for loop

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading: The first solution *is* a nested for loop. And the inner loop “early exits” as soon as possible, to improve the performance. Btw, in your `datesReversed` there are two events "2018-11-03 18:14:00 +0000 to 2018-11-03 21:44:00 +0000" and that why the code prints a conflict.

Comment: Im sorry i meant without using a nested for loop

Comment: i will try the very first solution now though

Comment: @CodingwhileLoading: The “zip solution” is only a way to implement the (single) loop with less code, but fully equivalent. I have added the “single loop solution” to make it clearer.

Comment: the new solution however does not account for every single time conflict.. i believe its because there is no second loop though.. Any insight on how to make the work ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201004/discussion-between-martin-r-and-coding-while-loading).

Answer (score 1):

You can extend `DateInterval` to check for overlaps events.

We can break it down into 3 validation to check: 
(assume event eventA is already set and you checking with eventB against it)

1. Checking if eventB starting after eventB starts and ends before eventA ends.
2. Checking if eventB ends after eventA starts and before eventA ends.
3. Checking if eventB starts before eventA starts and ends after eventA ends.
4. Cheking if eventA and eventB starts at the same time.

Giving that, I think this solution could do the work:

```html
extension DateInterval {
    func isOverlaps(with di: DateInterval) -> Bool {
        let answer =
            checkIfDItartAtTheSameTime(dateInterval: di) ||
            checkIfDIIsBetween(date: di.start) ||
            checkIfDIIsBetween(date: di.end) ||
            checkIfDIStartsBeforeAndEndsAfter(dateInterval: di)
        return answer
    }
    
    private func checkIfDIIsBetween(date: Date) -> Bool {
        return date > start && date < end || date == start
    }
    
    private func checkIfDIStartsBeforeAndEndsAfter(dateInterval: DateInterval) -> Bool {
        return dateInterval.start < start && dateInterval.end > end
    }
    
    private func checkIfDItartAtTheSameTime(dateInterval: DateInterval) -> Bool {
        return dateInterval.start == start
    }
}
```

Now, in you iteration, you can just check:

```html
[intervalA, intervalB].forEach { di in
      if di.isOverlaps(with: someOtherDateInterval) {
          print("conflict")
      } else {
          print("Not Conflicting!")
      }
}
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Note that `DateInterval` already has a [`intersects()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateinterval/1780364-intersects) method – there is no need to reinvent the wheel :)